# Disable particular orientations, system-wide

Tags: orientation

I'd like to install some software (willing to write it myself if necessary) on Android devices which will restrict them from rotating to particular orientations.

There are plenty of apps that will lock a particular orientation, but what I would like to do is say (for example) you are allowed any orientation but not reverse portrait.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Wait a minute, isn't reverse portrait **disabled by default** in Android? There are a number of people looking to **enable** it, even.

Comment: It is on most phones, but not all, and not tablets. I realize now my post only mentions phones, I'll update it.

Comment: Try Ultimate Rotation Control, it has a "forced 3/4 auto" mode that forces no reverse portrait globally (bonus: it also forces apps that usually do not rotate to rotate as you wish). If that does work I'll make it into a proper answer.